# PIX DirectX 11 Debug Pixel Error

Tags: c++, debugging, directx-11, dxgi, pix

I recently updated my DirectX 11 (C++) application for dual-monitor, dual-window support. Ever since then, when I try to debug any pixel in the PIX debugger, I get the following error:

```
A call that previously succeeded failed during playback:

EID: 1375 
Call: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() 
HRESULT: DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL

For more information click 'Help'.
```

I am no longer using D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain, but instead using D3D11CreateDevice and then CreateSwapChain to create separate swap chains for each of two windows (one per monitor). I used the SDK sample MultiMon10 as a reference when making my changes, however I can still debug pixels without error when running the MultiMon10 sample project through PIX. So it can't just be a matter of "CreateSwapChain" not being PIX-friendly.

Any ideas what could be causing this error? Debugging pixels and stepping through shaders has helped me out a lot in the past and I'd hate to lose that capability.

Comment: Sorry, I never did find a solution. I have since been using nVidia's NSight for graphics debugging. It is nice, but you need two computers to use it - one for running the debugger, and the other for running the software. This is because it allows real-time debugging of code running on your GPU, so it halts the GPU (and hence, the display) of the computer running the software.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I am hitting the same problem. It also happens with Visual Studio 2012 Graphics Debug. Must be something with CreateSwapChain in DX Debug mode.

I've been using [Intel's GPA tool](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/intel-gpa) instead to workaround this issue. I find it very useful. It can be used to debug on the same machine or through a client/server model.